# image version broken ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, menu, image-processing

I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04LTS and I have 2 image version: 5.3.0.28 generic (original installation) and 5.3.0.59 Uupdate version). This last version do not work. How can eliminate that version from boot menu ? or repair it? I run it with security option and didnt work, Only work the 5.3.0.28 generic image.

Answer (score 0):

According to blogs recomentation about this error, I edited de line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

adding the word nomodset,    "nomodset quiet splash"

sudo update-grub

And after reboot ubuntu works.!!

But I do not understand why this problem?

Comment: The problem is with video drivers installed a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. I did not install any video driver. Ubuntu did. There are not private driver in the installation. Hardware Graphic: Intel G33.